# excel data validation select from table

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

How can I create a datavalidation list that lets the user pick values from a table and based on that selection show another value from the same table. For example I have this table..

```
PlaceName       MapCoordinate
New York        https://xxxxxxxx/axQX7SfmbB72
Washington      https://xxxxxxx/vc7bhJY3Gxr
```

I want the user to select from the PlaceName column in a list, but the value that should be displayed should be the MapCoordinate value. Is this possible?

Currently I only have this formula in a list 
    =INDIRECT("PlaceNameTable[PlaceName]")

Or should I use vLookup in some way instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your datavalidation(list of names) in cell B1, then you can use in cell C1 for example `vlookup(B1,PlaceNameTable,2,0)`
which works on my test sheet.